# What currency is used in all of the Pokemon games?

Tags: pokemon-series

Ok, so I love to play Pokemon. Yesterday on the way home from school, I asked myself, What currency is used in pokemon? I imagine it would br Pokedollars. Is it or is it something else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The cleverly named [Pokémon Dollar](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Dollar) is the currency for Pokémon.

> Pokémon Dollar (Japanese: ポケドル Pokédollar) is the main currency used
>   in most known regions of the Pokémon world. Its symbol is [image], a P with a
>   double strikethrough, similar to the ¥ symbol used for Japanese yen or
>   the € symbol used for euro, with the P symbol referring to Pokémon.